# Cannot find module '@babel\runtime\package.json'

Tags: react-native, babeljs, package.json

I tried to run my app, but suddenly I have given this error.

**warn Package @babel/runtime has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module '@babel\runtime\package.json'**

but I have @babel\runtime in package.json
here is package.json's file

```
    {
  "name": "rasa",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "deprecated-react-native-listview": "0.0.6",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

How can I fix it, I don't want to initialize my project again, is there anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try `npm install` in command line and run again.